# Bad Request when using Google OAuth2.0

Tags: http, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce, google-oauth

I am receiving a 400 bad request when using Google OAuth from within Salesforce. The following error is in regards to invalid grant_type, but if you look at the documentation under 'Using Refresh Token' you will see that it is correct.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Error:

```
{
 "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
 "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

I am attempting to exchange a refresh_token for an access token and can successfully do it using CURL, with the following code.

```
curl \
  -d refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN \
  -d client_id=CLIENT_ID \
  -d client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET \
  -d grant_type=refresh_token https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

The code that I am using inside Salesforce:

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
    req.setHeader('client_id', 'CLIENT_ID');
    req.setHeader('client_secret', 'CLIENT_SECRET');
    req.setHeader('refresh_token', 'REFRESH_TOKEN');
    req.setHeader('grant_type', 'refresh_token'); 

    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token');
    req.setMethod('POST');

    return http.send(req);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-d` curl option sends the data in the request body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type which is one of the supported ways of sending those parameters in OAuth2.

> **`-d`** Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

In the Salesforce code you're setting the correct content type, but then are sending the OAuth2 related parameters as additional headers instead of sending them in the request body.

**You need to update the code to send the parameters in the request body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.**

Comment: req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

I modified the above line by removing the 'charset=UTF-8', but I still receive the same error listed above.

Comment: What you need to change is the way you pass the OAuth parameters like `client_id`, `grant_type`, etc. They can't use the `setHeader` and instead be passed in the POST request body.

Answer (score 7):

I caught the same issue in fiddler. I added this comment because it may be helpful to somebody.

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request Body:
code=<some code here>&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Goole api response:

```
{"error": "unsupported_grant_type",  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "}
```

The issue occurred because the request body has line breaks between each parameter. if you delete all the line breaks, leaving all values in a single row request will be work fine. e.g. request body:

```
code=<some code here>&client_id=your_client_id&client_secret=your_client_secret&redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: You saved me hours of experiments!