# Google Drive OAuth 2.0 Invalid grant_type

Tags: javascript, express, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Following the example from [OAuth2WebServer](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) from google I'm trying to set up an authentication flow from an express app using the HTTP/REST method they have but with every request I am returned with an error

I went through [Google OAuth “invalid_grant” nightmare — and how to fix it](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) but unfortunately it did not help.

```
{
  error: "unsupported_grant_type",
  error_description: "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

This is a shortened version of the error I am receiving. If you need to see more of the error let me know and I can post it.

### Server

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const { web } = require('./src/client_id.json');

const app = express();
const { client_id, client_secret } = web;

let count = 0;

app.use(express.json());

/*************************
** REDIRECT USER TO GOOGLE AUTH **
*************************/
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/auth';
  const scope = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly';
  const access_type = 'offline';

  res.redirect(`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=${ scope }&access_type=${ access_type }&redirect_uri=${ redirect_uri }&response_type=code&client_id=${ client_id }`);
});

/*************************
** ON AUTH WE EXCHANGE ACCESS TOKEN FOR REFRESH TOKEN **
*************************/
app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  count++;

  if (count >= 2) {
    return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
  }

  const { code } = req.query;
  const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/auth';
  const grant_type = 'authorization_code';

  axios.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', {
    code,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uri,
    grant_type
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    })
    // ALWAYS HITS THE CATCH "Invalid grant_type"
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('ERROR')
    });
});

app.listen(5000, console.log('Server listening on port 5000'));
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't use the official SDK? It could probably alleviate this error: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client

Comment: @FranciscoMateo Thanks for mentioning the official API. To be honest I really didn't think it was an option as it's not really mentioned for the server-side examples but only in the frontend/client side. YES there is a link in the server-side but this really threw me off. Hoping this works, thanks again.

Comment: it's probably a badly formed URL. Remember you need to URI escape the query params. I suggest construct the URL into a var and then console.log it. Compare this with a correctly formed URL from the OAauth playground

Comment: Maybe my comment will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63857783/1102149